# PS4 controller shows up wired, but not on bluetooth for Windows 10

Tags: technical-issues, ps4, controllers

Okay here's the dilemma: Steam's controller mapping recognizes my DualShock 4 controller when plugged in, DS4Windows recognizes my DualShock 4 controller when plugged in, and when I go to pair the device using Bluetooth the device is recognized... as "unknown" but it pairs as a wireless controller.

When the device is plugged into the PC I can see it in devices & printers, and even see it in the "test" area that pops up when you enter into "game controller settings". When I'm in that same game controller settings via wired, under advanced settings it displays: preferred device, wireless controller.

but then something funny happens via bluetooth. Even with little notifications popping up asking me to pair, even seeing its a wireless controller, it doesn't show up in Steam nor in DS4 Windows. It doesn't give me the option to put in "0000" as the code to sync. And the wireless controller shows up in devices & printers, but going inside of that area doesn't display anything. It's somehow being recognized as a wireless controller, but it's just not working at all as a wireless device.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to do something wirelessly on a controller on PC. Plugging it in is your only option. When you connect it wirelessly, it only works on mobile devices or consoles. In conclusion, on PC connect it with a cord, and on mobile devices or console, you can use it wirelessly. Don't worry, you're not the only one with this.